# Convert Base64 String into .wav file

Tags: android

I have a webservice that returns a base64 encoded string of an audio `(.wav)` file. I have tried this code:

```
 private String base64StringToFile(String base64AudioData) {

        String fullPath = null;

        byte[] decoded = Base64.decode(base64AudioData,1);
        //byte[] decoded = Base64.decode(encoded, 0);
        Log.e("~~~~~~~~ Decoded: ", Arrays.toString(decoded));

        try {
            fullPath = FileManger.getttsSavePath()+"/"+("fTts.wav");
            File file2 = new File(fullPath);
            //File file2 = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/hello-5.wav");
            FileOutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(file2, true);
            os.write(decoded);
            os.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return fullPath;
    }
```

This code creates a file but the file is not working. If I convert a `wav` file into base64 and then I use this code it works very well. But it's not working on the String which I am getting in the `api` response. There is nothing wrong with the string because the same string is working in the `iOS` version. So anyone please help me on it. This is the string which I am getting from the web service response.

> 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

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Decoding your response data, we can see that it's actually an error message:

> ```
> <html>
> <head>
> <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>
> <title>Error 406 x-nuance-sessionid18ec5e47-188a-4a21-a5ec-c7b0c1ce6628
> Received QueryError: 511 Voice not available. For a list of available voices, please see the Dragon Mobile SDK website.</title>
> </head>
> <body><h2>HTTP ERROR 406</h2>
> <p>Problem accessing /NMDPTTSCmdServlet/tts. Reason:
> <pre>    x-nuance-sessionid18ec5e47-188a-4a21-a5ec-c7b0c1ce6628
> Received QueryError: 511 Voice not available. For a list of available voices, please see the Dragon Mobile SDK website.</pre></p>
> </body>
> </html>
> ```

So your problem is not writing the .wav file, but rather your communication with the server (or a problem with the server itself).

Comment: my IOS colleague said that this is a NS data did you know what it means I may be wrong it's may be not base64 can you tell me how to play this as audio please help me

Comment: I guarantee you that this base64 string does *not* work in your iOS app. The data string you have is an error response from a server -- it is *not* valid WAV data. "NSData" is just a byte buffer class in iOS, but it is irrelevant to your problem. And yes, the input String *is* a valid base64 string -- it just doesn't contain the data you think it does.

Comment: Seriously, let me be as clear as possible: **your problem does not lie in the code you've posted**. The `base64AudioData` input argument contains an *error message* from a server, *not* any .WAV data.

Comment: OK Now i have confirmation that this is base64 data and my ISO colleague convert it into NS data and play but in android how can i play it please help me for this

Comment: *Your data is incorrect*. Your colleagues have different data.

Comment: Thanks for your contribution my problem has been resolved you were right there was a problem with my String now i am getting write response from server. many thanks Snild

Answer (score 0):

Try this, this is the example for convert base64 to .wav and vice versa

```
File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/hello-4.wav");
byte[] bytes = FileUtils.readFileToByteArray(file);

String encoded = Base64.encodeToString(bytes, 0);                                       
Utilities.log("~~~~~~~~ Encoded: ", encoded);

byte[] decoded = Base64.decode(encoded, 0);
Utilities.log("~~~~~~~~ Decoded: ", Arrays.toString(decoded));

try
{
    File file2 = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/hello-5.wav");
    FileOutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(file2, true);
    os.write(decoded);
    os.close();
}
catch (Exception e)
{
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for reply Joy I am already using this code see my above code in question i just modified this code which you have posted